# Install neo4j-enterprise on debian buster from official repo does not work

Tags: neo4j

Install neo4j-enterprise on debian buster from official repo doesn't work.

[image: Terminal]

> neo4j-enterprise : depends of: cypher-shell (< 1.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known problem. Try that command in the meanwhile:

> sudo apt install neo4j-enterprise cypher-shell=1.1.12